# You must add a reference to assembly mscorlib, version=4.0.0

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having some trouble migrating a web project from RC1 to RC2. When I switched, I'm getting a bunch of these errors throughout the project.

> The type 'Func<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Looks like all of the linq functions and lambda expressions are not working.

This is what my `project.json` file looks like:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Linq": "4.1.0-rc2-24027"
      },
      "imports": [ "net451", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0-*"
  }
```

Any ideas what this means? I've tried running `dotnet restore`, did not help.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Could you share your whole project.json?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues when using the `imports` argument. Try removing it entirely or changing net451 to dnx451

Comment: @Negorath good idea, also consider looking at what is added in a *new* RC2 web application. The imports section is `"dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"`

Answer (score 84):

I had the same issue and adding the following package to my `project.json` dependencies fixed it for me:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
```

This package enables compatibility with mscorlib-based PCLs.

Comment: Adding version 1.0.1 got me past this error. Thanks.

Comment: Have the same issue but i still have 1 error `Reference to type 'IListSource' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found.
`

Comment: This also works for referencing external projects built with .NET Framework4+ from within an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application.

Comment: Life saver - I already made a PR to an open source repo porting them to .NET Core before I found this. Can't do it for all of them though

Comment: This!!! Three days of Googling and I still couldn't build in Visual Studio (could build from `dotnet build` though). Adding `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility` finally fixed it, and I didn't run across this solution anywhere else (in the myriad obsolete articles that suggested editing project.json).

Comment: Having the same issue, however adding this did not resolve my issue... Also tried adding 1.0.2.  Still looking for a fix.

Answer (score 47):

In fact, the problem is an old lib that requires an asp.net 4.0 or 4.5 vesion (less than Core).

Microsoft provides a solution for it by installing the fallowing NuGet package.

> Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility

this way you will be able to run your code with old libs.

Answer (score 13):

Delete the **.csproj**.user [as per in the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IclOf.png) present in the solution folder.
Unload the project from solution explorer.
Reload the project and build it once. This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2019 for a MVC 5 .NET Framework 4.8 web application. Thank you.

Comment: Same as Ian here. It solved the issue on VS2019/FW 4.8/MVC5. Thanks

Comment: I didn't even have to build.  Just unload the project, delete that file, reload the project, done.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I created a new project using the template **Class Library (.NET Standard)** and ported some code into it that I wanted to re-use.

I created a new project **Class Library (.NET Framework)** and moved the code there instead and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error all of a sudden while working in a unit test project. Tried the suggestions as mentioned before like unloading and reloading the project, rebuild etc. Eventually all it took was a restart of Visual Studio - *Did you try to turn it off and on again* :-) VS version 16.11.5

Answer (score 2):

For MVC 5, you must add 2 references
Right click the project, and add reference

**Assemblies > Framework**

Add this 2 references

- **System.IdentityModel 4.0.0.0**
- **System.IdentityModel.Services 4.0.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

Adding this here in the hopes it'll help someone else, though my scenario was not a web project.
When loading a winforms form (designer) I was getting the error Unable to find assembly 'mscorlib
I deleted that file's resx file and let the designer re created it.
This happened after copying a form that was created in a .netframework project to a .net6 project.

Again, not related to the OP but this was the closest SO thread I could find to my problem

Comment: That solved the problem for me, thank you! In order to create a new .resx file just doubleclick the form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment but Matt Kemp's post lead to my solution . In my case it was using a **Class Library(.Net Standard)** instead of **Android Class Library (Xamarin)**

Comment: please provide the code rather than writing 2 lines, even if you don't have reputation you can help by answering but with examples.

Answer (score 0):

mscorlib reference is added by default, but it seems to be a visual studio reference issue. I have deleted my project and created new one then it worked fine.