# Reference to type 'IListSource' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to add my package in which is the target framework is `.Net Framework 4.5` Already add the `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"` to fix the  [mscorlib error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468552/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-mscorlib-version-4-0-0)

Below is the project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta902",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0"
},

"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "version": "1.0.1",
                "type": "platform"
            },
            "Clemittance.Database.ReadModel": "1.9.5"
        },
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8",
            "net45",
            "dnxcore50"
        ]
    }
},
```

`Clemittance.Database.ReadModel` is my package

Error
[image]

[image]

Comment: it is indeed in the `System.dll` but under the `System.ComponentModel` namespace. add a `using System.ComponentModel;` to the file.

Comment: @Nkosi Its already added but still same error

Comment: According to packagesearch it's in `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` package, http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=IListSource. Also remove `net45`, you are not supposed to abuse it like this.

Comment: @Tseng When i remove `net45` the output says `Package Clemittance.Database.ReadModel 1.9.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Clemittance.Database.ReadModel 1.9.5 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)`

Comment: @jayvee: That's correct. You can't use libraries which target .NET 4.5 with .NET Core. There is no automagical converter. If you must use libraries which require .NET 4.5 you also must target `net451` instead of `netcoreapp1.x`. Putting `net451` in import will only force nuget to restore the package, but nothing else. It do not convert your code to .NET Core/NET Standard

Comment: @Tseng ok i got it. I will just mark your answer. Thanks. But is `.NET Framework 4.5` compatible in linux? or is it only for windows?

Comment: Well, .NET Framework 4.5 is windows only, it's the old monolithic framework/runtime. You may be able to run it on linux with mono (you still target `net451`), but that depends on API used since not all APIs are directly ported in mono (i.e. encryption is different and some namespaces differ, WCF, WPF etc. (see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ on what's supported/ported to Mono)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is, remove `net45` from your import section, you are not supposed to abuse it this way. You are only allowed to use .NET Core compatible frameworks here, like `portable-net45+win8`, which are know to work with .NET Core because they share the same API surface.

NEVER use `imports` like that. It is only there to force nuget to restore certain nuget packagages, which are not yet targeting `netstandard1.x`, like certain Portable Class Libraries (PCL).

Abusing it for anything else, will just not work. You can't make .NET Framework 4.x libraries automagically work with .NET Core.

`IListSource` seems to be part of .NET Core but not of the "core" .NET Core packages. However packagesearch says it's in the `SystemSystem.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` package (see http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=IListSource).