# ASP.NET Core migration to 1.1 - Razor can't load types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

After upgrading my project from 1.0 and `project.json` to 1.1 and `.csproj` using VS2017, the project runs fine in VS, but when start it using `dotnet run` (or deploy it to Azure), all the views fail.

The error message is this:

```
One or more compilation references are missing. Possible causes include a missing 'preserveCompilationContext' property under 'buildOptions' in the application's project.json.

The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
+
    public class _Views_News_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<MyTeam.Models.General.PagedList<ArticleViewModel>>

.........
```

It seems as if the views are unable to compile because they don't have access to the C# stuff.

I am running on .NET Framework 4.6.1. This is my csproj: https://github.com/severisv/MyTeam/blob/master/src/MyTeam/MyTeam.csproj

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: i hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468552/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-mscorlib-version-4-0-0

Comment: How is it going? Have you resolved this?

Comment: Yes. When I changed to a windows 8 machine it worked. I will investigate it some more on my windows 10 machine when I get time, but until then I can't provide a solution I'm afraid. Worth noting is that publishing to azure from my windows 10 machine also failed, but publishing to azure from the other machine works, so my guess is that it is related to the behaviour of dotnet publish.