# .Net Framework You must add a reference to assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

After updating and including some NuGet packages, I now get many compile errors similar to:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I looked at [You must add a reference to assembly mscorlib, version=4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37468552) but I'm not running .Net core - this is an ASP.NET MVC, .Net Framework 4.7.2 Project.

There is no project.json to update. I already included the Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility NuGet package to no effect.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try restarting all instances of Visual Studio, cleaning and building the solution, and running `Update-Package -Reinstall` in the NuGet console. You may need to try another clean + build after running `Update-Package -Reinstall`.

Comment: Also, sometimes checking in the `/packages` folder into source control can cause issues like this. Remove it from source control and re-download the project and try again (make sure the NuGet restore happens).

Comment: @LewsTherin No change (though the Reinstall did throw a warning, unsure if that's related - "Directory 'Content' is not empty. Skipping..."). My packages folder is part of the .gitignore.

Comment: @LewsTherin Tried deleting the local repo, re-cloning, and doing it again... This time it worked. No idea what the problem *was*, but it's gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness's sake, I'll include the fix that actually worked for me as an answer.

Just delete the repo, re-clone, and try again.

Comment: I was in same situation after installing some NuGet package, and solved it similarly. Code cleanup may mot be practical for large codebases. Getting a clean repo will be quicker.

Answer (score 4):

Right-Click on your project and click Clean Solution in Visual Studio, and then try building it again. Solves the problem most of the time for me.
Or else, in case you copy-pasted a class from somewhere else, try creating a new class in your project and instead, copy-paste the code within the other class instead of just copying the class itself.

Comment: I deleted the class I created and tried it again copying the code in from somewhere else. Why does this work and why or how would VS even know the difference? It's a damn text file!

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue, I got this when I was trying to install EntityFramework.
Code Clean-Up worked for me.  Go to analyze and then try to run code cleanup using both profiles.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me - I had over 300 errors showing stating 'object' is not defined, etc.
I tried reinstalling the packages using Update-Package -Reinstall
and it went to over 1530 errors!!!  There is a bug in VS references handling.
This started after last update to Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.31.

To fix -

1. Execute Build - Clean Solution
2. In Package Manager console, ran: Update-Package -Reinstall
   (done to ensure all packages are intact)
3. Close all instances of Visual Studio
4. Checked Task Manager to ensure no Visual Studios hung (have seen this in past)
5. Reopened the project Solution
6. Clicked Build - Build Solution - Build Solution
7. No errors reported, Rebuild Solution again, no errors.

It reoccurs:
After starting/debugging multiple times for a couple days - suddenly it started showing errors again.  I did the above process again to clear - stayed clear for a few days.
I'm guessing there is some internal Visual Studio error in last VS 2019 build.

Comment: Thank you Todd - Nipped it!  Same environment, same error.  I was making a lot of changes when this error showed up.