# Why do I see errors in Error List when build is successful? VS2019 V4.8.04084

Tags: visual-studio-2019

After doing a Rebuild All, and getting a "successful" build (which runs via F5, BTW), I see 74 errors in the Error List, starting with this one:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 19_Statistics.aspx  C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\xxxx\Statistics.aspx  1   Active

This behavior seems sporadic; if I close/restart VS, I probably won't see it for "a while", but the symptom always seems to recur.   Is there something not configured properly that would cause this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365974/net-framework-you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-mscorlib-version-4-0-0-0

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for that; good info; we'll see if those things help. Curious as to why that article didn't show up under "related questions" :)